# my dockerised django app doesn't run when adding nginx

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I'm trying to dockerise my django app and trying to serve it using nginx. I'm not sure what's wrong but the nginx redirected to the correct URL but the django app doesn't load at all.

for example if I open URL `http://localhost:8000/cas/login/?service=http://localhost:8000/` which served by gunicorn, the app loaded properly. Yet when going to `http://localhost:1337/` I would be redirected to `https://localhost/cas/login/?service=http://localhost/` and would show unable to connect. I'm not sure what's wrong. Any pointer would be appreciated.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "4.0"
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'atshrd_db'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql/dbb:/var/lib/mysql
      
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_container
      #command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
    command: sh -c "gunicorn --chdir /django/project --reload project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
      #command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /django/project --reload project.wsgi:application
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./project/hrd/static:/var/www/static
      - ./project/hrd/media:/var/www/media
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /django
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY /project ./project
RUN pip install cmake
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install opencv-python-headless
RUN pip install mediapipe tensorflow==2.11.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.27.0
RUN pip install face-recognition
RUN pip install django_datatables_view
RUN pip install django_cron
RUN pip install dlib
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
EXPOSE 8000
```

nginx.conf

```
#upstream django_container {
#    server app:8000;
#}

server {

    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/media/;
    }

        # Django static
    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem. All I had to do was change the port in docker-compose.yml from ` 1337:80` to `80:80`. Not sure why it works though.